# How ng-model work in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I'm wondering on what basis `ng-model` works, in `input` it works with the value attribute, but is it possible to work with any other attribute?
this example is good one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<input style="background-color:{{myCol}}" ng-model="myCol">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now it understands that whatever typed in the textbox will be converted into a CSS value for the `background-color` property

Comment: Here you have a complete definition of what ngModel actually does: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel TL;DR: it just binds the value on inputs/textareas/etc to variables on scope. Then you use them wherever you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`ng-model`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) only binds value to variables of the scope.

You can access values of the scopes by several other directives. In your example, you may use [**`ng-style`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle):

```
<input ng-style="background-color: myCol" ng-model="myCol"/>
```

Comment: Updated, I think it better fits what you asked.